# Generating table rows for a form using js

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see, the following is pretty ugly and seems to be unnecessarily long.
Is there a shorter/neater way to do this?

```
function addNewRow(body, id){ 
    var myRow = document.createElement("tr");
    myRow.id = id+'';
    var c1 = document.createElement("td");
    var c2 = document.createElement("td");
    var c3 = document.createElement("td");
    var c4 = document.createElement("td");
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    myRow.appendChild(c1);
    myRow.appendChild(c2);
    myRow.appendChild(c3);
    myRow.appendChild(c4);
    myRow.appendChild(d);

    var i1 = document.createElement("input");
    var i2 = document.createElement("input");
    var i3 = document.createElement("input");
    var i4 = document.createElement("input");

    i1.type = 'text';
    i1.id = 'drwID_' + id;
    i1.name = 'drwID_' + id;
    i1.disabled = !editing;

    i2.type = 'text';
    i2.id = 'pos_' + id;
    i2.name = 'pos_' + id;
    i2.disabled = !editing;

    i3.type = 'text';
    i3.id = 'stm_' + id;
    i3.name = 'stm_' + id;
    i3.disabled = !editing;

    i4.type = 'text';
    i4.id = 'note_' + id;
    i4.name = 'note_' + id;
    i4.disabled = !editing;

    c1.appendChild(i1);
    c2.appendChild(i2);
    c3.appendChild(i3);
    c4.appendChild(i4);
    body.appendChild(myRow);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use loops. Really, that's about it - all of the element creation and appending can be done in a loop, while the prefix for each of the element's `name` and `id` be stored in an array.

```
function addNewRow(body, id) {
    var myRow = document.createElement("tr"),
        d = document.createElement("div"),
        inputPrefix = ['drwID_', 'pos_', 'stm_', 'note_'];

    myRow.id = id + '';

    for(var i = 0; i < inputPrefix.length; i++){
        var td = document.createElement('td'),
            input = document.createElement('input');

        input.type = 'text';
        input.id = inputPrefix[i] + id;
        input.name = inputPrefix[i] + id;
        input.disabled = !editing;

        td.appendChild(input);
        myRow.appendChild(td);
    }

    myRow.appendChild(d);
    body.appendChild(myRow);
}
```

You are generating invalid HTML here though - `tr`s cannot contain `div` elements.

Comment: Thanks!

I didn't think of storing the prefixes in an array, that's why i couldn't figure out a way to loop it. You're right about the div too, that thing isn't supposed to be there...